# Kendo UI Grid - not working in IE for POST/DELETE requests

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having problem getting the Kendo Grid to work correctly.  I am using ASP.NET WebAPI to fetch data from SQL Server and display it in the grid.  Use the Kendo Grid to do Updates and Deletes.

POST: While debugging I noticed that a NULL object in IE but Chrome gets a valid data.
which I am passing to update the DB.

IE versions 10 and 11.  There are no JS errors but the object is NULL on the WEB API.

**WEBAPI - GET Works (IE and Chrome),**
***POST/DELETE does not work in IE (Works in Chrome)***

```
    @model dynamic

    @{
       ViewBag.Title = "FunctionalGroup";
     }

    <div class=".col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-lg-8">
      <div class="well well-sm">
      <h2>Functional Groups - Management</h2>
      <p>Create, Update and Delete Functional Groups</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">            
      <div class="well well-sm">
        <div style="overflow-x: auto" id="FunctionalGroupGrid"></div>
        <div id="window"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div> 
      <button data-role="button" data-icon="cancel"></button>
    </div>
    </div>          
       @section Scripts{

      <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="windowTemplate">
      <p>Delete <strong>#= FunctionalGroupName #</strong> ? </p> 
          <p>#= FunctionalGroupDescription # </p> 
    <button class="k-button" id="yesButton">Yes</button>
    <button class="k-button" id="noButton"> No</button>
    </script>

    <script>

    var windowTemplate = kendo.template($("#windowTemplate").html());

    var window = $("#window").kendoWindow({
        title: "Are you sure you want to delete this record?",
        visible: false, //the window will not appear before its .open method is called
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        width: "400px",
        height: "200px",
    }).data("kendoWindow");


    var LookupFunctionalGroupType = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: "/api/FunctionalGroupType",
            datatype : "json"
        }
    });

    function getfunctionalGroupType(functionalGroupTypeID) {
        for (var idx = 0, length = LookupFunctionalGroupType.length; idx < length; idx++) {                
            if (LookupFunctionalGroupType[idx].FunctionalGroupTypeID === functionalGroupTypeID) {
                return LookupFunctionalGroupType[idx].FunctionalGroupTypeName;
            }
        }
    }

    function functionalGroupTypeDropDownEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "FunctionalGroupTypeName",
            dataValueField: "FunctionalGroupTypeID",
            dataSource: LookupFunctionalGroupType
        }).appendTo(container);
    }

    $(function () {

        var baseUrl = "/api/FunctionalGroup";
        var datatype = "json";
        var contentType = "application/json";

        var datasourceFG = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            serverPaging: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            autoSync: false,
            batch: true,                
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: baseUrl,
                    dataType: datatype,
                    contentType: contentType
                },
                create: {
                    url: baseUrl,
                    dataType: datatype,
                    contentType: contentType,
                    type: "POST"
                },
                update: {
                    url: baseUrl,
                    dataType: datatype,
                    contentType: contentType,
                    type: "PUT"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: baseUrl,
                    dataType: datatype,
                    contentType: contentType,
                    type: "DELETE"
                }
                , parameterMap: function (data, operation) {                        
                    if (operation !== "read" && data.models) {
                        return kendo.stringify(data.models);
                    }
                    else {
                        return {
                            take: data.take,
                            skip: data.skip,
                            pageSize: data.pageSize,
                            page:data.page
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            schema: {
                data: "Data.$values",
                total: "RecordCount",
                model: {
                    id: "FunctionalGroupID",
                    fields: {
                        FunctionalGroupID: { editable: false, type: "number" },
                        FunctionalGroupName: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                        FunctionalGroupDescription: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },

                        FunctionalGroupTypeID: { field: "FunctionalGroupTypeID", type: "number", defaultValue: 101 },

                        IsActive: { editable: true, nullable: false, type: "boolean" },
                        CreatedBy: { editable: false, nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                        CreatedDateTime: { editable: false, type: "date", format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}" },
                        ModifiedBy: { editable: false},
                        ModifiedDateTime: { editable: false, type: "date", format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}" }
                    }
                },
            }
        });

        $("#FunctionalGroupGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: datasourceFG,
            navigatable: true,
            autoBind: false,
            pageable: true,
            resizable: true,
            reorderable: true,
            editable: kendo.support.mobileOS ? "popup":true,
            groupable: true,
            filterable: true,
            sortable:true,
            columnMenu: true,
            selectable: "row",
            mobile: true,
            toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
            columns: [                        
                    { field: "FunctionalGroupID", width: 50, title: "ID", hidden: true },
                    { field: "FunctionalGroupName", width: 150, title: "Functional Group" },
                    { field: "FunctionalGroupDescription", width: 200, title: "Description" },
                    {
                        field: "FunctionalGroupTypeID", width: 180, title: "Functional Group Type"
                        , template: '#=getfunctionalGroupType(FunctionalGroupTypeID)#'
                        , editor: functionalGroupTypeDropDownEditor, filterable:false
                    },
                    {
                        field: "IsActive", width: 80, title: "Is Active",
                        template: '<input type="checkbox" #= IsActive ? checked="checked" : "" # disabled="disabled" ></input>'
                    },
                    { field: "CreatedBy", width: 100, title: "Created By", hidden: true },
                    { field: "CreatedDateTime", width: 100, title: "Created DateTime", format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", hidden: true },
                    { field: "ModifiedBy", width: 100, title: "ModifiedBy", hidden: true },
                    { field: "ModifiedDateTime", width: 100, title: "Modified DateTime", format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", hidden: true },
                    {
                        title: "Actions",
                        command: [
                            {
                                name: "destroy",
                                text: "Delete",
                                click: function (e) {  //add a click event listener on the delete button
                                    var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); //get the row for deletion
                                    var data = this.dataItem(tr); //get the row data so it can be referred later
                                    window.content(windowTemplate(data)); //send the row data object to the template and render it
                                    window.open().center();

                                    $("#yesButton").click(function () {
                                        grid.dataSource.remove(data)  //prepare a "destroy" request 
                                        //grid.dataSource.sync()  //actually send the request (might be ommited if the autoSync option is enabled in the dataSource)
                                        window.close();
                                    })
                                    $("#noButton").click(function () {
                                        window.close();
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
            ]
        });

        LookupFunctionalGroupType.fetch(function () {
            LookupFunctionalGroupType = this.data(); //First fetch the Lookup data
            datasourceFG.read(); // This will bind to the grid.
        });
    });

     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which versoin of IE are you running? Are you seeing JS error in IE?
I see in your secript

```
},
            }
```

You might want to remove "," if there are no elements following it in the list